# How to periodically repeat a function until success in background in Django?

Tags: python, django, scheduling, periodic-task

I'm working on a Django project. I want to do a http request to an external server. But sometimes the external server returns 5xx. I want to retry request on the background until it returns 200. How can I do this?
This is a pseudo code of what I want to do:

```py
response = requests.post(url, json=param)

if response.status_code == 200:
    # do something
elif response.status_code >= 500:
    # schedule task to retry every 30 seconds until success
```

Comment: what does "in background in Django" mean in your understanding?

Comment: check out pybreaker  https://github.com/danielfm/pybreaker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the download task is not a synchronize task, you need a task queue to archive your goal.

[Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/) is distributed task queue which could be easily integrated with Django.

You can create a download task like this:

```
from proj.celery import app

@app.task(bind=True)
def download(self, url, param):
    response = requests.post(url, json=param)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # do something
        ...
    elif response.status_code >= 500:
        # schedule task to retry every 30 seconds until success
        raise self.retry(countdown=30)
```

To call your task:

```
download.apply_async(('YOUR DOWNLOAD URL', None))
```

References about celery:

1. [Celery task usage](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html).
2. [How to integrate celery with into django](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
import time

RETRY_TIME = 30

referenceTime = time.time()

while(1):
    currentTime = time.time()
    dt = currentTime - referenceTime

    if(dt > RETRY_TIME):
        referenceTime += RETRY_TIME
        print("hello")

        #   do your request here

        if(response.status_code == 200):
            break
```